# Strcmp wont return zero for same two same strings

Tags: c, csv, fgets, scanf, strcmp

I am reading in a CSV file using fscanf which has two fields.

```
datatype_t*read(FILE* fp)
{
 char name[66];
 char data[1466];
 if (fscanf(fp, "%[^,] %[^\n]", name, data) == 2) {
    datatype_t *d = (datatype_t*)malloc(sizeof(datatype_t));
    d->name = strdup(name);
    d->data = strdup(data);
return d;
}
return NULL;
}
```

CSV file data is as following

Mr Dave,School teacher
Mike,Head
Sachin,staff member

Now I am reading another text file which has data in it.

```
char buffer[66];
    if (fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL ) {
        keydata_t *k = (keydata_t*)malloc(sizeof(keydata_t));
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
    if(buffer > 0 &&  buffer[len-1] == '\n'){
        buffer[--len] = '\0';
}
k->name = strdup(buffer);
return k;
}
return NULL;
}
```

Data of the txt file looks like this. 
Mr Dave
Ron
Mr Tim

Now When I compare the data strings:

```
new_ptr = root; 
while((keyt = read_key(keyfile))!= NULL){

    printf("%s\n", keyt->name);
    printf("%s\n", root->key);
    if(strcmp(keyt->name, root->key) == 0){
        printf("match\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(keyt->name, root->key) > 0){
        printf("not equal\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(keyt->name, root->key) < 0){
        printf("not equal\n");
    }
    new_ptr = search(new_ptr, keyt);
}
```

It keeps printing 
 not equal 
even for Mr Dave where there should be a match. I cant seem to figure out the problem with the two.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Or at least, have you printed what the program read?

Comment: @GMichael : Yes it prints out the names correctly yet it says that they are not equal when it goes through strcmp !

Comment: this line: `if (fscanf(fp, "%[^,] %[^\n]", name, data) == 2) {` will include the comman `,` as the first character of the second parameter.  suggest: `if (fscanf(fp, "%[^,] %c %[^\n]", name, data) == 2) {`

Comment: in C, the returned type from the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  casting the returned type just clutters the code and makes it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest removing the cast.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value before using it, to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both) `d` is meaningless, even in the current posted code.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability, 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. 2) make use of (consistent) horizontal and vertical spacing

Comment: what is this expected to mean: `if(buffer > 0 &&  buffer[len-1] == '\n'){`   the expression `buffer > 0` will ALWAYS be true because in C, referencing an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  Perhaps you meant: `if( len > 0 &&  buffer[len-1] == '\n'){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `man fgets`:

`fgets`  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

`fscanf` **does not** store the newline in the buffer.

Please try checking what the last symbol of `keyt->name` is and remove it if it is the newline

Comment: Even if it is a newline it would print out when I try to debug it by putting print statement. It only printed out the name and no new line was printed after each name

Comment: When it returns into main, I tested out what it prints and it only prints the name. Something like this
     printf("%s %s\n",keyt->name, root->key);
     It outputed Mr Dave Mr Dave
Yet it doesn't say match when it string compares

Comment: There is `\n` in the `printf`'s format. Try printing using something like `==%s==\n` to see if anything is embedded into the string. Even better, print byte-by-byte in hexa form.

Comment: So when I printed out using ==%s==\n such as(printf("==%s==\n", keyt->name);) 
it outputted Mr Tim ==e for some reason.

Comment: Tried this ? if(strcmp(keyt->name && root->key) == 0)

Comment: @Technologeek : Yes, It says too few arguments to function call error

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should print every character of strings you want to compare as hex/dec values. It is possible strings contain characters that are printed in console but you can not see them. Visible output may look the same but it can still differs. Printing (for example) hex values will show you exactly what is inside strings.

Then if output will be the same for both strings and strcmp will still return something other than 0 you should worry (but I am sure it won't be :)